# Por que essa atribuição de variável é possível no Python?

Tags: python, variáveis, condição

```
test = 1 and 2
if test == (1 and 2):
     print('Python')
```

Como a variável test pode receber essa operação lógica? "1 and 2"

Comment: Porque o "retorno" de `1 and 2` é o resultado de uma comparação, que deve ser um valor, no caso 1 and 2 irá retornar `2`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing, que é um valor *Truth*

Comment: Veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations): `1 and 2` é uma expressão que retorna um valor, e esse valor pode ser atribuído a uma variável (mas vale lembrar que isso **não** está verificando se o valor de `test` é 1 ou 2)

Comment: E só pra completar, `if (test == 1 && test == 2)` é uma condição que nunca será verdadeira (não tem como a mesma variável ser 1 e 2 ao mesmo tempo, provavelmente vc quis usar `||` em vez de `&&`). Esse mesmo teste em Python seria `if test == 1 or test == 2 ` ou ainda `if test in (1, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que sempre comece os estudos pela documentação, no básico é explicado como os operadores funcionam, para o caso especifico:

- [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- [Boolean Operations — and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Primeiro deve entender quais tipos de objeto são valores [considerados verdadeiros (ou falsos)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Qualquer objeto pode ser testado (***Truth Value***), para uso em uma condição `if` ou `while` ou como operando das operações booleanas abaixo.

Por padrão um objeto só **não** é considerado verdadeiro se sua classe defina um método `__bool__()` que retorne `False`, exemplo:

```
class Bar:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False


foo = Bar()

if foo:
    print("True")
else:
    print("false")
```

Ou um método `__len__()` que retorne `0` (zero), quando chamado com o objeto, exemplo:

```
class Bar:
    def __len__(self):
        return 0


foo = Bar()

if foo:
    print("True")
else:
    print("false")
```

E também temos *objetos built-in* considerados *falsos*:

- constantes definidas como falso: `None` e `False`.
- zero de qualquer tipo numérico: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
- sequências e coleções vazias: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

---

Depois é necessário entender como os operadores se comportam:

### Operador `x or y`

Este é um operador de *curto-circuito*, portanto ele **só avalia o segundo argumento se o primeiro for *falso***.

### Operador `x and y`

Este é um operador de *curto-circuito*, portanto ele **só avalia o segundo argumento se o primeiro for *verdadeiro***.

### Operador `not x`

`not` tem uma prioridade mais baixa do que os operadores não booleanos, portanto `not a == b` é interpretado como `not (a == b)` e `a == not b` causará um erro de sintaxe.

---

### Testando o exemplo da pergunta

No seu exemplo `teste = 1 and 2` irá atribuir o valor `2`, assim como `(1 and 2)` irá resultar em `2`, ou seja, sua variável ***não** recebeu 1 e 2 ao mesmo tempo*

```
test = 1 and 2
print(test)      # irá imprimir 2

print((1 and 2)) # irá imprimir 2
```

Como explicado, é um operador *curto-circuito*, o primeiro valor é *Truth*, portanto avaliará o segundo (resulta no valor `2`), se o primeiro valor fosse `0 and 2` iria atribuir `0` a sua variável:

```
test = 0 and 2
print(test)      # irá imprimir 0

print((0 and 2)) # irá imprimir 0
```